# Forcing font size of bootstrap-select (.selectpicker) element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

How can I set the font size of a bootstrap-select to a certain size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give font size to any select just by applying the following css. apply !important to override css loaded after your style.

```
select {
  font-size: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: While this is true, this is also extremely risky, as EVERY select field anywhere on your website will have a font-size of 50px. So be careful and try to be way more specific with the selector, e.g. `.someclass form select {}`